# Update default printer name during runtime

Tags: macos, cocoa, printing, runtime

Right now, I have a few lines of ObjC to poll for a default printer being set, and in my app it should update a label with that new printer's name, but so far it isn't working.

In my controller, I have the following:

```
[self updatePrinter];
```

Which calls this tiny method:

```
- (void)updatePrinter {
    NSPrintInfo *printInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];
    self.printerName.stringValue = printInfo.printer.name;

    NSLog(@"Printer: %@", printInfo.printer.name);
}
```

when it hits my method (in `viewDidLoad`), it will populate the label `printerName` properly.

I tried adding a timer to poll for the new printer default being set:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updatePrinter)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

This runs correctly, but if I open system preferences, and change the default printer, it continues to print the name of the old default. It will only behave differently if I restart the app.

How can i get the new default to be reflected in my app during runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the same `NSPrintInfo` object again, create a new object with

```
[[NSPrintInfo alloc] initWithDictionary:@{}];
```

Comment: Thanks. I came up with a really complicated solution by comparison, involving the PM* functions, and thought initWithDictionary: required all the settings. This works very simply and efficiently for me.